# How to show this sequence not convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let the real sequence $x_n s.t. \Vert x_{n+2} - x_{n+1}\Vert = M \Vert x_{n+1} - x_{n} \Vert$

If the $0< \vert M \vert <1$, then $x_n$ surely convergent since it is a contractive.

But the $\vert M \vert =1 $, we can't say the $x_n$ is converge or not when taking the example $x_n = {1 \over n}$

So I guessed the case $\vert M \vert >1$, My provisional conclusion was that $x_n$ is diverge when the $\vert M \vert >1 $, started proving myself. But I don't have any idea how to show it. Hence, how to show this sequence not convergent on $\mathbb{R}$ when the $M(\in \mathbb{R})$ is a positive which is $\vert M \vert >1$ ?
 Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x_1 \neq x_2$.

$\|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}\|=M^{n-1} \|x_2-x_1\|$ for all $n$. RHS tends to $\infty$. If the sequence is convergent then  LHS tends to $0$.

Now I will leave to you think about the case $x_1 \neq x_2$. [See if $x_k \neq x_{k+1}$ for some $k$].  Note that the hypothesis is satisfied if $x_n$ is a constant sequence and the sequence converges in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $M >1$;

$b_n:=|x_{n+1}-x_n|$;

Let $n_0$ be a positive integer, s.t. $b_{n_0} >0.$
(Such a $n_0$ exists (Why?))

$b_{n+1} >b_n$, an increasing sequence, bounded below by $b_{n_0}>0$ for $n \gt n_0$.

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}b_n \not =0$.

Hence $x_n$ does not converge (Why?)